# Detect if element in iFrame is in Client-View

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I want to detect if an element in an `<iframe>` is in Client-View of the Main-Frame.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mplwx.png)

The problem I face is, that the element is always in View for the `<iFrame>`. But I am unable to detect if the Element is in View for the Main-Frame.

In this Example, think, that the element (Div) is at Pixel 2500. And i want to mdetect from outside the `<iframe>` if the element is in View

```html
<html>
<body>
<div style="background-color: red;" width="100%">
Menu
</div>
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/" width="100%" height="3000px">
</body>
</html>
```

**Need's to work in IE**

Comment: The iframe's document is on the same domain? If so, you can simply use an IntersectionObserver.

Comment: @Kaiido same Domain, but I Need to use IE, so IntersectionObserver dosent work.

Comment: These are information that should be in your question. Also, clarify precisely if IE is your main target, or if you only need to support it for some customers. Because if more than 50% of your users are not using IE, an IntersectionObserver should be used for them, as it is a lot more efficient than any workaround (i.e "it saves trees"), and the workaround could be applied only for IE users.

Comment: @Kaiido oh yeah, my mistake! 100% of my users use IE in my specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `IntersectionObserver` works and you want to support it in IE, you could use [this polyfill](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/main/polyfill). This library polyfills the native `IntersectionObserver` API in unsupporting browsers and it supports IE 7+.

Comment: Sound processing, will test it!